An example of a morphism of schemes that is not separated
Definition. A morphism of schemes $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ is separated, if its diagonal morphism $(1_X, 1_X)_Y : X \longrightarrow X \times_Y X$ is a closed immersion.
Is there an example of a morphism of schemes that is not separated?
My intuition is that every morphism of schemes is separated.
Proof: Assume that $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ is a morphism of affine schemes. Then we can assume that $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $Y = \operatorname{Spec} B$. Then $(1_X, 1_X)_Y$ corresponds to the morphism of rings $A \otimes_B A \longrightarrow A$, which is obviously surjective. So $(1_X, 1_X)_Y$ is a closed immersion.
For a general case, we can assume that $U$ is an affine open subset of $X$ and $V$ is an affine open subset of $Y$ such that $f(U) \subset V$. Then we can apply the argument above to $U$ and $V$. Since these $U$s can cover $X$, we deduce that $f$ is a separated.
What is wrong of the proof?

If you use $\operatorname{Spec} A$ to format $\operatorname{Spec} A$, you will get nicer spacing than your previous method. I've made the upgrade for you this time.

The problem with the proof is that $U\times_V U$ as $(U,V)$ runs over the pairs of affine opens $U\subset X$, $V\subset Y$ with $f(U)\subset V$ do not cover $X\times_Y X$. Therefore you cannot conclude that $X\to X\times_Y X$ is a closed immersion. Using the standard first example of a non-separated morphism where $X$ is the affine line with doubled origin and $Y$ is a point, if $0_1$ and $0_2$ are the two origins in $X$, then $(0_1,0_2)$ is not in any affine open of the form $U\times_V U$, but it is in the closure of $X\to X\times_Y X$.

Why the sets $U \times_V U$ do not cover $X \times_Y X$? Assume the projections are $p,q$. For every $r \in X \times_Y X$, $f \circ p(r) \in V_1$ for some open affine subset $V_1 \subset Y$. Then we can find an open affine subset $U_1 \subset f^{-1}(V_1)$ such that $p(r) \in U_1$. We can have $U_2, V_2$ for $q$. So $r \in U \times_V U$, where $U = U_1 \cap U_2$ and $V = V_1 \cap V_2$.

@Functor In the example above, $(0_1,0_2)$ is not in any $U\times_V U$. In your proposed explanation, there is no guarantee that $q\in U_1$, so that $(p,q)\notin U\times_V U$.

The standard example is "the line with double origin", that is
$$
X = \mathbb{A}^1 \cup_{\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}} \mathbb{A}^1,
$$
the gluing of two lines $\mathbb{A}^1$ along the identity morphism on the puctured line $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$, while $Y$ is just a point.
